# Azure Service Principal - Account Disabled?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I'm having trouble authenticating to Azure Resource Manager with a service principal.  In the course of troubleshooting I noticed that `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` shows `AccountEnabled: False` for my service principal, while `Get-MsolServicePrincipal` shows `AccountEnabled: True` for the same service principal.

```
C:\Users\virklba> Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString azuremaint |fl

ServicePrincipalName : https://mycompany.com/AzureMaint
ApplicationId        : 20bc779d-0edb-4a00-becf-952fda93edc5
AccountEnabled       : False <-----------
DisplayName          : AzureMaint
Id                   : 585cd6c7-403a-4940-9817-5139a254245e
Type                 :

C:\Users\virklba> Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ObjectId 585cd6c7-403a-4940-9817-5139a254245e

ExtensionData         : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AccountEnabled        : True <-----------
Addresses             : {Microsoft.Online.Administration.RedirectUri, Microsoft.Online.Administration.RedirectUri}
AppPrincipalId        : 20bc779d-0edb-4a00-becf-952fda93edc5
DisplayName           : AzureMaint
ObjectId              : 585cd6c7-403a-4940-9817-5139a254245e
ServicePrincipalNames : {https://mycompany.com/AzureMaint, 20bc779d-0edb-4a00-becf-952fda93edc5}
TrustedForDelegation  : False
```

I tried doing `Set-MsolServicePrincipal -ObjectId 585cd6c7-403a-4940-9817-5139a254245e -AccountEnabled $true`, but that didn't change anything.  There is no `Set-AzureADServicePrincipal` cmdlet.
So how do I make sure the account is really enabled?

Comment: how have you configured your service principal ? it should have been granted permissions to Azure Service Management API as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx

Comment: I followed these instructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/

Comment: I created another service principal following the instructions you linked - same result.  Maybe it's a bug in `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`.

Comment: but your service principal is working, it is just this property value from the powershell ? You can run fiddler and inspect the calls and results from the powershell.

Comment: Good point.  Fiddler shows that the API call behind `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` is returning `accountEnabled=True`, so apparently it is an issue with `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`.  
I still can't get my service principal to work in Azure Automation, but that's for another question.

Comment: For Automation, you have to manually upload the ARM PowerShell module. By default there only is the Service Management API.

Comment: Yep, did that, followed joe's recent blog post on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed with MS that this is a bug in the PS module. Also, I documented my "service principal in Azure Automation" issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31485415/310446) (ended up being another PS bug).